# How does the c compiler execute when we include a pointer declaration to a structure which we haven't finished defining yet?

Tags: c

```
struct noderecord {
    struct noderecord* next;
    int data;
};
```

how is the pointer next declared without some error? we have added one more element subsequently after declaring a pointer, wouldn't the pointer element be of the wrong size?

Comment: Re “we have added one more element”: That is a member. Structures have members. Arrays have elements.

Comment: You seem to think that `sizeof(struct noderecord *) == sizeof(struct noderecord)`, but that's not the case. The first one is fixed, while the second depends on the structure members.

Comment: Even if the size of `next` would depend on the actual size of the struct (which is not the case, see answer below), the compiler could just read the entire struct definition and then act accordingly.

Comment: In the declaration of the member `struct noderecord* next;`, the `struct noderecord` type is incomplete, but that is OK because pointers to incomplete types are allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All pointers to structures in a C implementation are the same size as each other, per C 2018 6.2.5 28:

> … All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other…

So, to know how big a pointer to a structure is, the compiler does not need to know anything about the structure, just that the pointer is pointing to some type of structure.